# install4j launcher doesn't work on macOS

Tags: java, macos, install4j, launcher

I have a Java project and I'm using Install4J to deliver and launch. On Windows and Linux anything is fine, but on Mac the launcher app doesn't work (it appears for a moment then exits). Media for macOS is macOS single bundle.

macOS version is 10.13.2 (17C88) and Install4J version is 7.0.3.

LE: The updated question is how can I see the console log or stderr output.

Comment: What appears for a moment, your UI? Once your UI appears, install4j is no longer involved and the JVM is running on its own.

Comment: From the Launchpad, I click on my app icon, it appears for a moment in the taskbar (not on the screen) and then exits.

Comment: Got it. You can execute it from the command line `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub` to see the standard error output. If nothing is printed, execute it like this `INSTALL4J_LOG=yes MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub` to get debugging information from the native launcher.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out (the error). You can put your comment to the answer - this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the application bundle from the command line with

```
MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

to see the standard error output. If nothing is printed, execute it like this

```
INSTALL4J_LOG=yes MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

to get debugging information from the native launcher.